# What if we don't install tensorflow under a new environment?

Tags: matplotlib, tensorflow, libraries, environment, pandas-datareader

How come we need to install tensorflow as a [separate](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33768560/33234120-05bba17a-d1ef-11e7-9f8a-0390d005aa6a.png) environment?

If we do it this way, many common libraries are not available when tensorflow is activated.

[image]

Most of the common libraries such as matplotlib, panda, etc. are not within tensorflow environment. So we have to install again to use them.

[image]

So why not just install under root so we don't have to re-install all those libraries under the new environment?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't *need* to. But you have to live with the consequences. Not sure if there any, it's easy to check. But imagine tf want's numpy <= 1.11. Then installing to root will downgrade numpy if you got a newer one. (imaginary example)

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean by "will downgrade" if you got a newer one? Also, wouldn't it be troublesome and inconvenient if we have to re-install all those libraries one by one if we need to run tensorflow at the same time? Cuz they are not within tensorflow by default.

Comment: You can only have one version installed for any given lib. Imagine your root has numpy 1.13.3, the newest one. Now, imagine for some reason TF-devs decided not to support numpy 1.13 because something changed and it's not working out for TF. This will be reflected in their install-script. In regards to pip this would be something like ```numpy < 1.13```. In terms of prebuild binaries it's probably handled differently. But this is a restriction and the package-manager which is active needs to find some combination of libary-versions now to fulfill all reqs. numpy 1.13.3 will replaced by 1.12.x.

Comment: Now the above need for replacing numpy 1.13.3 with 1.12. can have the effect on your other lib X, which has a req. like ```numpy>=1.13``` (sometimes there is no solution!). This is package-conflict resolving at it's best. So other libs might be effected. Using virtual-environments combats that with envs build for some specific use-case. Most often only needed for very complex software with a lot of strict requirements. There is no problem in having many virtual-envs, besides HDD-space. They don't interfere with each other!